# Transporting important people

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> I have a ship with many important people on board.
>
> On the deck I see a little over 50 people. A few of them are kings.
>
> Many of the passengers are black, including two of the kings.
>
> There is a John, a Joseph and a Julius on board, but no Jack.

Who are the people on board my ship?

Hint:

> No corpses on board, all are living people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The people on board are ...

> ... the heads of state of the members of the [**African Union**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Union).

In particular:

> The African Union has 55 members. Three are monarchies: Morocco, Lesotho and Swaziland (or eSwatini, as it is called now). **King Mswati III** of Swaziland and **King Letsie III** of Lesotho are black. The three J's are **John Magufuli**, President of Tanzania; **Joseph Kabila**, President of the Democratic Republic of the Congo; and **Julius Maada Bio**, President of Sierra Leone. None of the African heads of state is called Jack.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Nice work.

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly clear that:

> The 'people' on board are *playing cards*. A pack of cards contains four kings, two red, two black.

I believe that John, Joseph and Julius are:

> Popes. Pope John, Pope Joseph, Pope Julius.

Because:

> There are a number of very old card games involving popes. One called "Pope Joan" is played on a board. Another is called "*Pope Julius*" but apparently very little is known about the rules. There are Jacks in a pack of cards but there was never a "Pope Jack". The pope is considered an "important person" as in the title of your puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

They are:

> A pack of cards

Except:

> Without one Jack, who I guess is you?

Comment: Who are the John, Joseph and Julius?

Comment: @hexomino the other "jack"s